# Cassandra using 'like' in query condition

Tags: cassandra, cql

When I query from Cassandra with a CQL statement of:

```
select * from abctpl where tpl like  '1-1'
```

In the table, the content of tpl which I want is '1-1-1', and it's unique. 
 But actually I get 3 rows. The other two tpls do not contain a string '1-1-1', I guess Cassandra regard '-' as a wildcard character. If tpl's word like '11111111' also can be selected.

So how can I edit the CQL to make it query the exact data?

Comment: Is there a question here?  Because I don't see one.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the question at the end of description.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from abctpl where tpl like  '1-1';
```

I think the problem here, is that you're not providing the LIKE wildcard character `%`.  If your SASI index is defaulted to PREFIX mode, then this should work:

```
select * from abctpl where tpl like  '1-1%';
```

Take a look through the DataStax docs on using SASI indexes: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html .  That has some query examples, along with how to specify the mode at index creation.

> make it query the exact data?

And if it's *exact* data that you're after, using equals (`=`) does a better job of that than `LIKE` does.